# Possible to compile/run iOS over bluetooth with XCode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it possible at all to compile and run applications using bluetooth instead of the iPhone dongle cable using xcode? I just think this little added support would be welcome by developers who would love that feature like I would.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 4.2 supported building and running applications over WiFi to an iOS device. Unfortunately they dropped the feature in Xcode 4.3 because of too many issues.

Honestly, I would rather have the speed of a cable, especially the new Lightning connector over the convenience of not having to use a cable.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I wish the feature existed and was fast enough : (

Comment: I doubt it would be slower than switching devices connected to your mac, and not to mention the number of cables needed for testing on multiple devices at the same time.

Comment: +1 for the info abou old Xcode versions. But hey, it takes 0.74 seconds to send 5MB over an average 54Mbit/s Wifi. It takes half a day to find someone who lends you his cable when you forgot yours. Moreover, what if you want to debug while a USB device is connected to your phone? Moreover, if the feature existed, cable-lovers could still use cables.

Answer (score 0):

No. At the moment that feature is not available to developers. Although, that would be a welcome feature. Unfortunately, it would be slower and less reliable, therefore Apple has not implemented it.